# What´s a good source to learn about literature reviews?

Tags: literature-review

I read this: "All types of literature reviews including systematic reviews, integrated reviews, bibliometric reviews, content analyses, hybrid reviews, etc., as long as they are not descriptive, are encouraged". I only knew about descriptive reviews.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE! Although I understand the value of this question, I don't think this is an appropriate question for this site because your question is opinion-based. It is rather subjective what is a good or a best source on introductory material for literature reviews.

Comment: That said, rather than giving you an official answer, I will happily write here in a comment the best article I have found that distinguishes different kinds of reviews, in my opinion: Paré, Guy, et al. "Synthesizing information systems knowledge: A typology of literature reviews." Information & Management 52.2 (2015): 183-199. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.im.2014.08.008

Comment: Even though it focuses on the information systems discipline, its categories are fairly universal, at least across the social sciences.

Comment: This question might be closed as a "shopping question" (we don't generally recommend books, etc., though I personally would be inclined to make an exception for things like this). That said: a new post here asking what the difference between these five different types of reviews is might be well-received (just guessing, no guarantees).

Comment: @Tripartio I don't think it's an opinion-bsed question, as there are objective criteria available to spot good sources. The most obvious indirect measurement of "goodness" is citation count. That said, the way the question was asked could indeed be improved to force objectiveness on the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a [good introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Review_article) to different types of review. On that web-page, under the heading of [Categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Review_article), there are brief descriptions of different types of review, with further links to additional information.

If you have not previously encountered anything other than a descriptive review, the Wikipedia page seems like a good place to begin.

Answer (score 1):

A good source to learn about Systematic Literature Reviews is:

- [KEELE, Staffs et al. Guidelines for performing systematic literature reviews in software engineering. 2007.](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Barbara-Kitchenham/publication/302924724_Guidelines_for_performing_Systematic_Literature_Reviews_in_Software_Engineering/links/61712932766c4a211c03a6f7/Guidelines-for-performing-Systematic-Literature-Reviews-in-Software-Engineering.pdf)

Comment: This is only for software engineering though

Comment: @cconsta1 Correct. But OP did not specify which area he will reasearch about, and I know that this source I pointed is good. Therefore, the suggested answer does indeed answer the original question: "What´s a good source to learn about literature reviews?". Any good source would do.

Comment: Cool, I upvoted it :)